# How to get the serialized size fast?

Tags: java, serialization, kryo

Is there any way to find out how big will be the byte array returned after serializing an object with Kryo? Or do I have to actually serialize it and then check the array's length?

For instance, with LZ4, before compressing a byte array, I can get a bound for the compressed size even before compressing...